# MysQL and PHP Calculating totals

Tags: php, mysql

I am sorry if this seems a little vague, but I am trying to stretch myself here and I am not sure of the right terms to use.

I know how to manipulate a simple mysql database, and, using php, show the query on a web page.

I am thinking about seeing if I can create a simple World Cup 2014 match predictor for friends and colleagues,

I am looking to build a structure that will allow them to predict (using a web page form) either a "home win" "tie" or "away win" for each of the games, data that will be stored in a record with an ID unique to that player.

I will then manually add the correct details as the competition goes along into another table.

I understand how I can cross reference these on the fly in a web page, and build a web page that will show the running total of correct answers for individual players, but is there something I can set up so that the database can cross reference itself, and add the total correct answers into a field in each row?

The flow would be... if PLAYER.GAME_1_PREDICTION = RESULTS.GAME_1_ACTUAL THEN ADD 1 TO PLAYER.POINTS_TOTAL - and so on for each of the 64 games - can anybody help get me started here, this is something I would really like to learn!

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to COUNT the results of a JOIN between the predictions table and the results table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ps.player, COUNT(*) as player_points_total
FROM predicted_scores ps
JOIN actual_scores acs ON ps.game_id = acs.game_id 
WHERE ps.score = acs.score
GROUP BY ps.player
```

Comment: would I also be able to sort them by player_points_total as usual (ORDER BY player_points_total DESC)?

Comment: @BillTeale yes you can sort as usual

Comment: @BillTeale I believe the way it works with joins is MySQL creates a temporary table out of the retrieved data, and so of course then you can sort by any column in that "table".